# PHP/Redhat7: where do I find php-mcrypt package?

Tags: php, redhat

I need to use the module. I tried searching for it and it's not available!

I've read the mcrypt_encrypt has been decrated in PHP7+.

But I've also read that mcrypt_encrypt and openssl_encrypt will not give the same output. and the 3rd app (abandoned by vendor) I'm passing this value expects I used "MCRYPT_3DES" cipher

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
$text = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $tempstring, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
```

Any ideas? Thanks

```
[user@my-here.com]$ sudo yum list vailable "*mcrypt*"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Error: No matching Packages to list

[user@my-here.com]$ sudo yum list vailable "*mbstring*"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Installed Packages
php-mbstring.x86_64           5.4.16-42.el7  @development-RHEL-7-x86_64-Optional
Available Packages
php54-php-mbstring.x86_64     5.4.40-4.el7   development-RHEL-7-x86_64-RHSCL    
php55-php-mbstring.x86_64     5.5.21-5.el7   development-RHEL-7-x86_64-RHSCL    
rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64  5.6.25-1.el7   development-RHEL-7-x86_64-RHSCL    
rh-php70-php-mbstring.x86_64  7.0.10-2.el7   development-RHEL-7-x86_64-RHSCL
```